# "cost incurred before" vs "cost incurred until"?

Tags: word-usage, time

I am wondering which of the following is correct/preferable:

> We need to take into account the cost incurred **until** action is finally
>   taken.

vs

> We need to account for the cost incurred **before** action is finally
>   taken.

For a bit of context: this passage refers to an hypothetical scenario where someone procrastinates until they finally address the issue at hand. The sentence wants to draw attention to the fact that there **are** costs associated with this delay in taking action.

Comment: Could it be phrased as "we need to consider the costs incurred while action is pending (or delayed)?"  Normal people will understand you either way, but nerds like me will consider your sentence to be equivalent to "until/before action is taken, we need to consider the cost incurred."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends on where the cost is cumulative or just a fixed cost. If the cost rises the longer they take,

> We need to take into account the cost incurred until action is finally taken.

is probably the best to use.

If a fixed price

> We need to account for the cost incurred before action is finally taken.

would be a suitable option. To be on the safe side, I would go for 'until' every time.

Comment: thank you for this. If I don't really have a mental model of whether this cost is cumulative or fixed, but instead want to stress the fact that it could have been avoided (if only action had been taken on time), which of the two would you pick?

Comment: 'Until' is your best choice here, it makes it clearer that it's a penalty charge rather than just a regular fee.

Comment: It's worth noting that "We need to account for the cost incurred before action is taken" is a way of saying that if we do not do the accounting, some undesireable action will be taken as a consequence.

Answer (score 0):

The first is preferable, because *until* clearly modifies "incurred".

In the second, *before final action* may modify *account*.  i.e. the accounting must be completed before final action is allowed.  Or it may mean the same as the first, that at/after final action, all costs preceding that action will need to be considered.

So use the first version, avoiding the ambiguity.